# Angular2 validate form input fields

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm having trouble understanding how to upload a file(s) in a Angular2 form that holds other fields while validating the existence of such files.

I need the file inputs to `validate` that there is indeed a file in the field because at the moment angular2 won't detect the file. So far I have not found a concise example on how to validate file inputs in angular2 forms

The following snippets are a small hypothetical example of what my actual code is

In html template

```
<form [formGroup]="newCarRegistrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(newCarRegistrationForm.value)">
      <!-- ...other fieldsets -->
      <fieldset class="fieldset" formGroupName="assets">
        <legend class="text-5 legend">assets</legend>

        <div formGroupName="thumbnails">
          <div class="">
            <input type="file" 
                  formControlName="smallImage"
                  name="smallImage">
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
      <!-- ...other fieldsets -->
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!newCarRegistrationForm.valid" >Save</button>

</form>
```

In .ts component

```
import {
  Component, OnInit,
  ElementRef, ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: './...',
  styleUrls: ['./...']
})

export class newCarRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  public newCarRegistrationForm: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('fileinput') backgroundImage: ElementRef;

  // public smallImage: string = '';
  // public mediumImage: string = '';
  // public largeImage: string = '';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }

  assignFileOnChange(event, formKey) {
    this[formKey] = event.target.files[0].name;
    console.log(event.target.files[0].name, this[formKey]);
  }

  onSubmit(value: any): void {
    console.log(value);
  }

  initForm() {
    this.newCarRegistrationForm = this.fb.group({
      assets: this.fb.group({
        thumbnails: this.fb.group({
          smallImage: ['', Validators.required],
          mediumImage: ['', Validators.required],
          largeImage: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you mean existence of the file on the client side or that the user has selected a file ? Which one do you want to validate ?

Comment: validate a user selecting a file, I tried "watching" for changes on the form input fields but it didn't work

i.e I tried updating the `smallImage` variables on change and pass that as `smallImage: [this.smallImage, Validators]`

I know I'm missing an important piece but I don't which one